# div fills space when the value is empty

Tags: html, css

I have having the following code:

```
<div id="case-number-value" class="overview">{!orderLine.Case_Number__c} </div>
<div id="case-name-value" class="overview">{!orderLine.Case_Title__c}</div>
<div id="event-date-value" class="overview">{!orderLineDate}</div>
```

It works as the right part of a table and it works fine in normal cases. But when some value is empty/null, orderline.case_Number__c, for example, the whole right part of the table will shift up. Is there a way I can leave an empty space there if there is no value.

Please ignore the grammar of {!orderLine.Case_Number__c}, it is just salesforce way of using variable.

Comment: you could try setting the minimum height for your `div` element. It ensures that the height of your div is atleast what you specify in the stylesheet. [Relevant documentation](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_min-height.asp)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can put in

```
 &nbsp;
```

for cases when values are null or empty strings, like:

```
 if(someVar === null || someVar.toString().length==0){
 someVar = '&nbsp';
 } // Thats how I'd done it with Javascript.
```

nbsp stands for 'non-breaking space' which is widely used in HTML. You have not specified your programming language, so I can't provide the full solution with corresp. checks... If you are looking for HTML only solution, you can do the following:

```
<div id="case-number-value" class="overview">{!orderLine.Case_Number__c}&nbsp;</div>
<div id="case-name-value" class="overview">{!orderLine.Case_Title__c}&nbsp;</div>
<div id="event-date-value" class="overview">{!orderLineDate}&nbsp;</div>
```

As you could notice, I've put in non-breaking spaces after every variable, so even if it's value is "" or null, there still be nbsp there => the table won't collapse.